# Is there a way to edit the edges or borders of fontawesome icons?

Tags: html, css

I am currently a student learning HTML and CSS. I was tasked with an assignment to replicate a single webpage. However, I am having difficulties getting the icons to look like what is shown in the model provided to replicate. The images below show what the icon area of the model should look like versus what I have, and also what the original icons looked like when just added to the HTML before color or size adjustments were made.

[Original icon area of the model provided.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eDCn.png)

[How close I have gotten to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWlcm.png)

[Original icons before size and color adjustments were made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdpcO.png)

I need to get the edges to be sharp and the white areas above and below the icons to be removed. I tried setting the border-radius, margin, and padding to 0px or 0% and nothing still works. I also tried using text-shadow.

My HTML code for the icon area is

```
'<div class="icons">
        <i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-dribbble-square"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-tumblr-square"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-rss-square"></i>
    </div>'
```

And CSS

```
'i{
display: inline-flexbox;
font-size: 24px;
color: #3E5A99;
background-color: #E5EEFF;
margin-bottom: 50px;
}'
```

I am asking for some advice on how to get this done, please. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, you cannot edit the FontAwesome webfont icons without downloading, editing, and reuploading the individual svgs.

I would use the background-less versions of these icons and then put them each inside a `div`. Then you can set the div `border-radius`, `background-color`, etc. to exactly what you need.

A couple of pointers with this process:

Use `display: grid;` for each container div, that way you can also add `place-items: center;` to super-center each icon inside of it's div.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your suggestion. I will definitely try it and let you know if it works.

Comment: No matter what I do the icons still display that white area at the top and bottom of them.

Comment: Did you try changing the icons to their standard form? (e.g. `fa-twitter` instead of `fa-twitter-square`)?

Comment: Thank you very much @Calvin. I did what you suggested and with the addition of some padding around the element I was able to succeed at replicating the icons.